# Define a junk hand in poker

Tags: probability

I was watching my wife play video poker and, when she drew a junk hand, she always kept one card and drew four. I don't play poker any more, but when I did, I threw all of the cards away and drew five. I was wondering which was the better option.

The problem with that question is that I really don't know how to define precisely what a junk hand is. So, I decided to ask a simpler, but related question. Suppose I played a video poker game in which I had two choices,

```
 1. Pick any face card, deuce through ten, and then draw four more cards.   

 2. Draw five cards.
```

Which choice has the better chance of winning?

But the more I thought about it, the more I got interested in the original question. So that brings me to my question. How would you define a junk hand in a standard game of video poker?

I was thinking along the lines of

```
 A poker hand is a junk hand if replacing any one card would not
 result in a paying hand.
```

What do you think of that definition.

Comment: And you are shure it can be explained mathematically?

Comment: When you say video poker, are you playing like a slot machine, where there is a payoff for certain hands, or playing draw poker against other people?  If so, it matters how many other people.  Keeping an $8$ makes you more likely to wind up with a pair of $8$s.  That is more likely to win if there is only one opponent.

Comment: @Ramanujan:  you can certainly define  the chance to win against a probability distribution of other hands.  For many hands, the choice of draw is "obvious".  You would have to define what people will do with a hand like this, but it probably won't change the result very much.  You also have to define if they keep an ace with any pair, but aside from representing a stronger hand that is demonstrably a bad idea.

Comment: @RossMillikan - I mean the video poker machines at the Fiesta Casino in Henderson, Nevada. I watch a movie there while my wife throws nickels at those machines. Once I can come up with a good definition of a junk hand, I plan to find whether it is better to draw four or five cards where a win is considered anything equal to or better than a pair of face cards.

Comment: I suggest running a numerical simulation and do not spend money in a Casino. Win-win.

Comment: If I recall correctly (it has been years and the rules may have changed) the machines pay a small amount for a pair of jacks or better, but nothing for a lesser pair.  You should define the whole payoff schedule.  I suspect you should keep a face card if you have one.  Aces are a little more questionable because if you keep one you are less likely to get a straight than if you keep a jack, queen, or king.  You should also consider how many cards match in suit to the one you are keeping, as they decrease the chance of a flush.

Comment: @ross - You're missing the point. If I have a face card, then that is not a junk hand. If I have a possible flush, then that is not a junk hand. etc.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - If I could figure out what a junk hand is, then a Monte Carlo routine would be pretty easy to implement. The geezer rate for movies is less than ten bucks and the "locals" casinos tend to make sure that the locals want to come back. Over a year's time, with comps, it comes out to be about the same as dinner and a movie.

Comment: Wouldnt junk hand be hands with no faces and the number cards are not in a relation? Two cards would be in relation if they together have a non-zero probability of giving a winning hand? Or greater than some percentage if it works better

Comment: @ZelosMalum - A QH by itlself might give a winning hand. If I 2D and a 5S, I could draw three and try for a straight, but would I have a better chance at drawing five? I have to admit that my goal is to convince my wife to throw all five cards away. But I realize now that a completely useless hand is harder to achieve that I thought.

Comment: @StevenGregory i'd go for my relation idea, from it you can construct it further

Comment: The hands you are talking about are called high card hands.  They lose to a pair or any of the hands that occur less frequently than a pair.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - Thanks, a name goes a long way towards finding information on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided on this definition.
A hand is a junk hand if you cannot get a winning hand by drawing one new card.

Comment: ...with no justification whatsoever. How is this useful for anyone?

Comment: @winther - Since when does a definition need justification? This is going to be useful to me when I write my program and make some trial runs. Specifically, is discarding four cards at random better or worse, statistically, than discarding all of them?